# Angular 2 cannot import module when using AOT

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-aot

I have a simple angular module which does nothing:

`index.ts`: `export * from './my.module';`

`my.module.ts`:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
@NgModule()
export class MyModule {}
```

I have imported this module in my main application:

```
import {MyModule} from "my-module"
// OR: import {MyModule} from "../../node_modules/my-module/src/my.module"
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    MyModule,
  ],
  ...,
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Usually, everything works fine. However, if I try to compile AOT, I get the following error:

> ERROR in : Unexpected value 'MyModule in /my/path/node_modules/my-module/dist/my.module.d.ts' imported by the module 'AppModule in /my/path/src/app/main.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

If I do the import with the absolute path to the module source (`../../node_modules/my-module/src/my.module`), I get:

> ERROR in my-module/src/my.module.ts(7,2): Error during template compile of 'MyModule'
>
> Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'ɵmakeDecorator' was called in 'NgModule'
>
> 'NgModule' calls 'ɵmakeDecorator'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @BrunoFenzl I restructured the whole thing so sadly no, sorry